# X-Domain Form POST Becomes GET in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to POST a form to another subdomain in my company using javascript. The address is to an API that programatically generates a PDF and returns it "inline" so that instead of going to the Downloads folder it opens in a new tab.

This is working in all modern browsers, but it's not working in IE 9. Upon investigation, for some reasons my form is being submitted as a GET (with no body) instead of a POST. Here's my code:

**HTML**:

```
  <form id="pdfDownloadForm" style="display:none" method="POST" target="_blank">
  </form>
```

**Javascript**:

```
    var form = document.getElementById("pdfDownloadForm");
    form.setAttribute("action", apiUrl + "download/pdf");
    form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    input.setAttribute("name", "html");
    input.setAttribute("value", getHtmlToConvertToPdf());
    form.appendChild(input);

    form.submit();
```

Since I'm using jquery, I also tried `$(form).trigger('submit')`, just to see if it made a difference (it didn't).

Any idea why IE9 would decide to turn this into a GET? Is this an old cross-domain "safety" feature that I'm going to have to work around or is there just something I'm missing that will make IE9 behave the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because of IE security in Win 7
try 
Tools > Internet Options > Security > Internet/Local > Uncheck "Enable protected mode".

Comment: I tried doing that, but it didn't fix it. Plus, I can't really ask my users to do it anyway.